# Merge two different files using specific columns after a match and add N/A when no match

Tags: linux, bash, awk, merge

### File 1

```
Time        C-ID        Room            Info        N_Range ErrorCodes  Stability   Position    Profile Configuration   N-East  EAST    North
10:29:18    13832216    1Tr1Tr1Tr10     VILNARPN    AIN         6       STABLE      default     1600    8               LINK    R8      1
10:29:18    1498684     1Tr1Tr1Tr11     VILNARPN    UAN         6       STABLE      default     1600    5030            LINK    R8      1
10:29:18    1498684     1Tr1Tr1Tr12     VILNARPN    AN          6       STABLE      default     1600    5030            LINK    R8      1
10:29:18    2492427     1Tr1Tr1Tr13     VILNARPN    AN          7       STABLE      default     1600    5030            LINK    R8      1
10:29:18    1002527     1Tr1Tr1Tr14     TDAT00      AN          6       STABLE      default     1600    8               LINK    R8      1
10:29:18    1002527     1Tr1Tr1Tr15     TDAT00      UAN         6       STABLE      default     1600    8               LINK    R8      1
10:29:18                1Tr1Tr1Tr18     TDAT00      AN          5       STABLE      default     1600    8               LINK    R8      1
10:29:18    1569109     1Tr1Tr1Tr19     RTEDLOJ0    AIN         6       STABLE      default     1600    8               LINK    R8      1
```

### File 2

```
Number          Action      Time      Repeat    Oas  Restriction    Status      Priority
AA_B_43645175   REBUILD     15:29:18    2       OAS     NONE        PENDING     HIGH
AA_B_43652334   REBUILD     10:29:18    0       OAS     NONE        PENDING     LOW
AA_B_43652684   REBUILD     10:29:18    1       OAS     NONE        PENDING     LOW
AA_B_43653840   CHANGED     13:29:18    0       OAS     NONE        PENDING     MEDIUM
AA_B_43667706   REBUILD     10:29:18    2       OAS     NONE        PENDING     LOW
AA_B_43723080   REBUILD     10:29:18    4       OAS     NONE        PENDING     LOW
AA_B_43747934   CHANGED     10:29:18    1       OAS     NONE        PENDING     MEDIUM
AA_B_43766744   REBUILD     10:29:18    0       OAS     NONE        PENDING     LOW
AA_B_43908075   REBUILD     11:29:18    1       OAS     NONE        PENDING     LOW
AA_B_43963533   REBUILD     12:29:18    0       OAS     NONE        PENDING     HIGH
AA_B_43964358   NEW         13:29:18    3       OAS     NONE        PENDING     LOW
AA_B_43964533   REBUILD     14:29:18    0       OAS     NONE        PENDING     MEDIUM
AA_B_43964678   NEW         15:29:18    0       OAS     NONE        PENDING     LOW
```

if File1's first column matches File2's third column then print:

- Columns from File1: 2, 3, 6, and 7
- Columns from File2: 7 and 8
- mark N/A when there is no match

I tried

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$3];next}{print $2,$3,$6,$7,$2,$3a[$1]?a[$1]:"NA"}'
```

it didn't even do the Match

so I tried

```
awk -F 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$3];next} ($7,$8) in a' {print $2,$3,$6,$7,$2,$3a[$1]?a[$1]:"NA"}'
```

but it didn't work everything was marqued N/A

Desired Output

```
C-ID     Room        ErrorCodes     Stability   Status     Priority
1569109  1Tr1Tr1Tr19     6           STABLE     PENDING    LOW
1569109  1Tr1Tr1Tr19     6           STABLE     PENDING    LOW
1569109  1Tr1Tr1Tr19     6           STABLE     PENDING    LOW
1569109  1Tr1Tr1Tr19     6           STABLE     PENDING    LOW
1569109  1Tr1Tr1Tr19     6           STABLE     PENDING    MEDIUM
1569109  1Tr1Tr1Tr19     6           STABLE     PENDING    LOW
```

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: I did that but somehow it took the  picture, it didn't allow me to copy paste from excel sheet I don't know why

Comment: You can export as CSV, then print and copy/paste

Comment: If your files are excel spreadsheets, you're not going to be able to use normal shell tools like `awk` or `join`.

Comment: Your update isn't CSV... tabs, maybe?

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input. Also `it didn't work` is always the worst possible problem description, you've got to give us a clue about in what way it didn't work for us to be able too help you debug the problem - did you get no output, wrong output, error messages, core dumps, something else? What were you expecting that `-F` on it's own would do? Does the man page support that expectation?

Answer (score 0):

## Put File2 in an array and run each line from File1 over it

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# syntax ./merge-all.awk File2 File1

BEGIN {
  FS=","
  OFS=","
  lineCount=0
}

# Put File2 records into an array
FNR == NR {
  entries[lineCount, "time"]=$3
  entries[lineCount]=$7 OFS $8
  lineCount+=1
  next
}

# Print headers
FNR == 1 {
  print $2, $3, $6, $7, entries[0]
  next
}

# Print a record for each record in File2 while handling each File1 record
{
  matchFound=0
  for (i=1; i < lineCount; i++) {
    if (entries[i, "time"] == $1) {
      print $2, $3, $6, $7, entries[i]
    } else {
      print $2, $3, $6, $7, "N/A", "N/A"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the output of this command:

```sh
$ ./merge-all.awk File2 File1 | tr ',' ' ' | column -t
C-ID      Room         ErrorCodes  Stability  Status   Priority
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     PENDING  MEDIUM
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
13832216  1Tr1Tr1Tr10  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     PENDING  MEDIUM
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr11  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     PENDING  MEDIUM
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1498684   1Tr1Tr1Tr12  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     N/A      N/A
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     N/A      N/A
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     PENDING  MEDIUM
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     N/A      N/A
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     N/A      N/A
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     N/A      N/A
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     N/A      N/A
2492427   1Tr1Tr1Tr13  7           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     PENDING  MEDIUM
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr14  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     PENDING  MEDIUM
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1002527   1Tr1Tr1Tr15  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     N/A      N/A
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     N/A      N/A
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     PENDING  MEDIUM
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     N/A      N/A
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     N/A      N/A
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     N/A      N/A
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     N/A      N/A
null      1Tr1Tr1Tr18  5           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     PENDING  MEDIUM
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     PENDING  LOW
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
1569109   1Tr1Tr1Tr19  6           STABLE     N/A      N/A
```

Note that I added in the string `"null"` to the dataset where there was a missing `C-ID` as without any value there `awk` will shift all the columns left.

Comment: yes!! indeed Time is the common field between both tables, I need  to output that into a cvs format  can I use `OFS=,`

Comment: yes!! indeed Time is the common field between both tables, input is a csv file so I guess `-F,` should de the trick, I need  to output that into a cvs format  can I use `OFS=,` but I need N/A  for the field without a match

Comment: well it's not working nothing on the screen, I think it's the delimiter `-F,` I also added the N/A for unmatched fields, but no luck there either

Comment: What do you actually want for `N/A` output? An entire row of `N/A`?

Comment: And so, for each entry in File2 you'd like to find all of the matching entries (based on _Time_) in File1.

An entry of `10:29:18` Time in File2 would match all entries in File1 with `10:29:18` Time in your desired output correct?

Comment: Or is the output I have above good for you? (currently matching Time in File2 to the last one Time match in File1)

Comment: yes!! each time `10:29:18` is found awk will combined file1 and file2 based on the columns   file1:2, 3, 6, 7, and file2:7, 8 when there is no match awk will output  file1:2, 3, 6, 7,N/A. the input and the output are csv files. so I will need `-F` and `OFS=,`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216015/discussion-between-chrisbrownie55-and-driven).